# Why is css margin-right is not effective on angular 8, with clarity-ui?

Tags: css, angular, vmware-clarity

The css rule for right margin does not seem to be effective in angular 8 with clarity design system. See details below.

I have an angular 8 project with clarity design system. I have set it up with a header and vertical-nav as shown on the screen shot below:

In the content area I am experimenting with some css.
Problem:
The margin setting for rules below does not seem to be effective on the right.

styles.component.css:

```
.xxx {
    border: 2px solid #e7642c;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;}
h2, p {
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 80%;
    line-height: 1.4em;}
```

styles.component.html:

```
<div class="xxx">
  <h2>Moog</h2>
  <p>Moog synthesisers were created by Dr. Robert Moog under the company name Moog Music. Popular models include the
    Moog Modular, Minimoog, Micromoog, Moog Rogue, and Moog Source.</p>
</div>
```

screen shot:
[image: see right margin spilled out]
<sub>(source: [ebe.co.ke](http://ebe.co.ke/right-margin.jpg))</sub>

From the screen shot you can see, the text is spilling off. What am I not doing right or how can this be avoided?

Comment: Do not provide fix width to the inner elements like `h2` and `p`. Use `width:100%` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have given width: 200px; to h2 and p tags

instead of that you can try this

```
.xxx {
    border: 2px solid #e7642c;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
h2, p {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 80%;
    line-height: 1.4em;
}
```

The CSS box-sizing property allows us to include the padding and border in an element's total width and height.

Comment: Thanks Soothran, I have just tried your suggestion and it has worked. NB: The css snipet I was trying was from a book: [link](http://www.htmlandcssbook.com/code/). pg 307.